# DynamoDB Nested Query for Set of Object

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table called Group and it will have records like:

```
{
"id": "UniqueID1",
"name": "Ranjeeth",
"emailIdMappings": [
  {
    "emailId": "r.pt@r.com",
    "userId": 324
  },
  {
    "emailId": "r1.pt@r.com",
    "userId": 325
  }
]
},
{
"id": "UniqueID2",
"name": "Ranjeeth",
"emailIdMappings": [
  {
    "emailId": "r1.pt@r.com",
    "userId": 325
  },
  {
    "emailId": "r2.pt@r.com",
    "userId": 326
  }
]
}
```

I need to query and get result if emailId contains the input string.
I have reached so far and I am not able to get the result

```
AttributeValue attributeValue = new AttributeValue("r.pt@r.com");
Condition containsCondition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
            .withAttributeValueList(attributeValue);

Map<String, Condition> conditions = newHashMap();
conditions.put("emailIdMappings.emailId", containsCondition);

ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("Group")
            .withScanFilter(conditions);
amazonDynamoDB.scan(scanRequest) 
dynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(Group.class, scanResult.getItems());
```

For the above code I am expecting record with id UniqueID1, but it's empty. If you pass `"r1.pt@r.com"` then you should get both records.
sdk used is `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.155`

I tried posting the question in aws forum which didn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have List of Objects which has two attributes in a object (i.e. emailId and userId), you need to provide both values in order to match the item.

The `CONTAINS` function will not be able to match the item if the object has two attributes and only one attribute value mentioned in the filter expression.

Otherwise, you need to provide the occurrence (i.e. index) of the list to match the item.

**Example:-**

```
emailIdMappings[0].emailId = :emailIdVal
```